# How to get the same output example in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

I'm a beginner trying to learn about lists and arrays, especially with dimensional lists. I'm really struggling on how to do the code for the list shown in the output example. I would appreciate some help putting me in the right direction.

**Here's how I want the list to look like as a example**

```
# If I put in 4 as a example, the result will be this:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8], [0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]]

0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 4
0 2 4 6 8
0 3 6 9 12
0 4 8 12 16
```

my code down below:

```
def myNumber():
   chooseNumber=int(input("\nPlease enter a number between [1, 12]: "))
   while not (chooseNumber >= 1 and chooseNumber <= 12):
      print("That number is not between [1, 12], try again.")
      chooseNumber=int(input("Please enter a number between [1, 12]: "))
   print("Your number is:", chooseNumber)
myNumber()

#---- the code below I am struggling with here ----#

n = 4
[[i*j for i in range(n+2)] for j in range (n+2)]

# x = [ [1,3],[2,4] ]

print([[i*j for i in range(n+2)] for j in range (n+2)])
```

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Are you getting an error or an unexpected result?

Comment: @user1558604 no I'm struggling with how to do the lists right the same way as the example I showed

Comment: why are you using `n+2` rather than `n+1`?

Comment: @user1558604 like I said I'm a beginner trying to learn so I have little knowledge about this kind of stuff

Comment: `range(x)` will give the values `0,1,2,...,x-1`. So often you will see `range(x+1)` which will make the last value `x`. I think if you change your ranges to `range(n+1)`, you'll get the value you desire

Comment: Thanks @user1558604, do you know how to do the numbers horizontally?

Comment: `for row in xyz: print row` where `xyz` is your list comprehension. That will print a list on each row. If you don't want the brackets, then `for row in a: print(" ".join((map(str, row))))` This looks kinda complicated, but I'll break it down. `" ".join(*iterable*)` takes an iterable (of strings) and forms a string with each value of the iterable with a space in between. the `map(str,row)` part converts all of the `int` values in the `row` list to strings all at once. This is required for the `join` function (since it requires strings in the iterable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how to produce your desired output if I understand correctly:

```
n = 4

lists = [[i*j for i in range(n+1)] for j in range(n+1)]
outstr = ''
for i in lists:
    for n in i:
        outstr += str(n) + " "
    outstr += "\n"

print(outstr)
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 2 4 6 8 
0 3 6 9 12 
0 4 8 12 16
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much man, you did understand correctly and this is what I was looking for! I never know how to do those right, so thanks again dude you saved me.